# Can someone explain this algorithm for me? c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

i want to know how this code is working,

i can't understand the algorithm here

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Draw(int length) {

int cons = 3,L,l;
length -= length % 2;
L = length + cons;

for (int i = 0; i < L; i++){

    l = cons + i * 2 - 2 * (i == L / 2) - 4 *(i - L / 2) * (i > L / 2);
    for (int j = 0; j < (L-l) / 2; j++) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
        if (j == l/2)
            printf("|");
        else if (i == L/2)
            printf("=");
        else if (j == 0 && i < L/2 || (j == l - 1 && i > L / 2))
            printf("/");
        else if (j == l - 1 && i < L / 2 || (j == 0 && i > L / 2))
            printf("\\");
        else
            printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

Draw(5);
printf("\n");
Draw(6);
return 0;
}
```

I want clear clarification to this particular line, please :

```
l = cons + i * 2 - 2 * (i == L / 2) - 4 *(i - L / 2) * (i > L / 2);
```

this code should print this shape

[image]

[click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq6Zf.png)

or you can test the code here
https://ideone.com/49mtT4

and i apologize for any inconvenience

Comment: Off-topic. Consider compiling your code with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and running it step by step in the debugger (e.g. `gdb`). BTW it is more a matter of elementary math ([analytic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_geometry)) than a matter of C++

Comment: `(i == L / 2)` and `(i > L / 2)` these two values output either 1 or 0. consider `true` as 1 and `false` as 0;

Comment: It considers compiling! Off topic!

Comment: This program shouldn't even work. The function in (C\C++) is called `Draw()` and the `main()` is calling a function named `draw()`; renaming one or the other to be either lowercase or uppercase would make it compile though.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you you defined all your variables as int and you are making a calculation on boolean, it automatically convert that boolean into int. (i == L / 2) and (i > L / 2) these two values output either 1 or 0. consider true as 1 and false as 0.then you can understand the function

```
l = cons + i * 2 - 2 * (i == L / 2) - 4 *(i - L / 2) * (i > L / 2);
```

try follwing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void Draw(int length) {

    int cons = 3,L,l,test;
    length -= length % 2;
    L = length + cons;

    for (int i = 0; i < L; i++){

        l = cons + i * 2 - 2 * (i == L / 2) - 4 *(i - L / 2) * (i > L / 2);
        test = (i == L / 2);
        cout << "(i == L / 2):" << test<< endl;
        test = (i > L / 2);
        cout << "(i > L / 2):" << test<< endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Draw(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Which will output

```
(i == L / 2):0
(i > L / 2):0
(i == L / 2):0
(i > L / 2):0
(i == L / 2):0
(i > L / 2):0
(i == L / 2):1
(i > L / 2):0
(i == L / 2):0
(i > L / 2):1
(i == L / 2):0
(i > L / 2):1
(i == L / 2):0
(i > L / 2):1
```

https://ideone.com/PPwvRV

Comment: That is not a function but an *assignment expression*. Perhaps rewriting it using the [ternary operator `?:`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) could be helpful.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch isn't it if `(i = L / 2)` an assignment expression? but here `(i == L / 2)`. [link](https://ideone.com/ap7DLb) you can see that value of the `i` is not changed

Comment: Then entire `l = cons + i * 2 - 2 * (i == L / 2) - 4 *(i - L / 2) * (i > L / 2)` is an assignment expression, used as a statement. There is no assignment *statement* in C (every assignment is an expression, and most of them are used as statements)

Comment: Ok now i understand , thank you alot :]

but why java can't compile this code it's say bad operator first is int , second is boolean

can we do the same with java? (convert that boolean into integer automatically)
and thanks again :]

Comment: It is not Java, but C.

Comment: i know :D , but when i'm trying to do the same with java compiler can't understand ,how can we do the same?

Comment: In Java  a boolean can't be used other than in a if. with Java try `(i == L / 2) ? 1 : 0` something like that. I did not test it. Keep one thing in the mind, adding `(i == L / 2) ? 1 : 0`  will not add a branch at the assembly level.

Comment: Unfortunately It didn't work, anyway Thank you for answering my question:]